# jQuery on window.location.href execute this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to go from home.html to services.html, the class .services_profile is a sub-menu that needs to go to services.html and make the .services_profile_tab active

```
$(".services_profile").click(function(e){

    $('.nav-tabs li a.tab-profile').attr("aria-expanded","true").parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-tabs li a.tab-profile').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.tab-content').children().removeClass('in active');
    $('.tab-content .profile').addClass('in active');

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = 'services.html';
    },1000);

    // This does not work
    if (window.location.pathName.indexOf('services') >= 0) {
      $('services_profile_tab').addclass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: It's `window.location.pathname` and missing `.` in `$('services_profile_tab')`

Comment: you have a typo : `$('services_profile_tab')` missing a dot for the className : `$('.services_profile_tab')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the tab reference to the services page Either within the `url` or you can make use of `window.localStorage` to set the specific tab to get active on navigating to the specific page like this with passing a ref in the url with hash:

```
$(".services_profile").click(function(e){

    $('.nav-tabs li a.tab-profile').attr("aria-expanded","true")
                                   .parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-tabs li a.tab-profile').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.tab-content').children().removeClass('in active');
    $('.tab-content .profile').addClass('in active');

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = 'services.html#services_profile_tab';// pass the tab reference
    },1000);

});
```

now on the services page in the doc ready block:

```
$(function(){
  if (window.location.indexOf('services') >= 0) {
      var tab = window.location.hash.substr(1);
      $('.'+tab).addclass('active');
   }
});
```

---

Something you can do to pass the tab reference dynamically like:

```
window.location.href = this.className.split('_')[0]'.html#'+this.className+'_tab';
// so it results in
// services.html#services_profile_tab => when "services_profile" clicked
```

here `this.className` is the clicked element to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

The **[pathname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)** should be in lowercase in :

```
if (window.location.pathName.indexOf('services') >= 0) {
```

And also you've missing a dot `.` of class before `services_profile_tab` in :

```
$('services_profile_tab').addclass('active');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check the camel casing in `pathname`

Comment: What you mean @JohnR ? i just referred the line that should have `pathname` and not `pathName`.

Comment: Edited what ? you can check my edits (link just below the answer).

Comment: Okay. I think it will be better if you explain it clearly with do's and don't s.